# Trying to create a matching algorithm for doctors and hospitals in Python, stuck on conditions

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements, list-comprehension, matching

First of all, I would like to point out that I am quite a rookie in python so if my wording of or question itself sounds stupid, please bear with me, just trying to learn.

I created two dictionaries, one of doctors that assings a ranking to hospitals and one of hospitals that assings a ranking to doctors.
Doctors to hospitals:

```
{'Doctor_5': {1.0: 'Hospital_7', 2.0: 'Hospital_6', 3.0: 'Hospital_8', 4.0: 'Hospital_5', 5.0: 'Hospital_9', 6.0: 'Hospital_4', 7.0: 'Hospital_10', 8.0: 'Hospital_3', 9.0: 'Hospital_2', 10.0: 'Hospital_1'}, 'Doctor_9': {1.0: 'Hospital_9', 2.0: 'Hospital_8', 3.0: 'Hospital_10', 4.0: 'Hospital_7', 5.0: 'Hospital_6', 6.0: 'Hospital_5', 7.0: 'Hospital_4', 8.0: 'Hospital_3', 9.0: 'Hospital_2', 10.0: 'Hospital_1'}, 'Doctor_8': {1.0: 'Hospital_8', 2.0: 'Hospital_9', 3.0: 'Hospital_10', 4.0: 'Hospital_7', 5.0: 'Hospital_6', 6.0: 'Hospital_5', 7.0: 'Hospital_4', 8.0: 'Hospital_3', 9.0: 'Hospital_2', 10.0: 'Hospital_1'}, 'Doctor_1': {1.0: 'Hospital_1', 2.0: 'Hospital_2', 3.0: 'Hospital_3', 4.0: 'Hospital_4', 5.0: 'Hospital_5', 6.0: 'Hospital_6', 7.0: 'Hospital_7', 8.0: 'Hospital_8', 9.0: 'Hospital_9', 10.0: 'Hospital_10'}, 'Doctor_4': {1.0: 'Hospital_5', 2.0: 'Hospital_6', 3.0: 'Hospital_4', 4.0: 'Hospital_7', 5.0: 'Hospital_3', 6.0: 'Hospital_2', 7.0: 'Hospital_1', 8.0: 'Hospital_8', 9.0: 'Hospital_9', 10.0: 'Hospital_10'}, 'Doctor_3': {1.0: 'Hospital_4', 2.0: 'Hospital_3', 3.0: 'Hospital_2', 4.0: 'Hospital_1', 5.0: 'Hospital_5', 6.0: 'Hospital_6', 7.0: 'Hospital_7', 8.0: 'Hospital_8', 9.0: 'Hospital_9', 10.0: 'Hospital_10'}, 'Doctor_6': {1.0: 'Hospital_7', 2.0: 'Hospital_8', 3.0: 'Hospital_6', 4.0: 'Hospital_9', 5.0: 'Hospital_5', 6.0: 'Hospital_10', 7.0: 'Hospital_4', 8.0: 'Hospital_3', 9.0: 'Hospital_2', 10.0: 'Hospital_1'}, 'Doctor_7': {1.0: 'Hospital_8', 2.0: 'Hospital_7', 3.0: 'Hospital_9', 4.0: 'Hospital_6', 5.0: 'Hospital_5', 6.0: 'Hospital_4', 7.0: 'Hospital_3', 8.0: 'Hospital_2', 9.0: 'Hospital_1'}, 'Doctor_10': {1.0: 'Hospital_10', 2.0: 'Hospital_9', 3.0: 'Hospital_8', 4.0: 'Hospital_7', 5.0: 'Hospital_6', 6.0: 'Hospital_5', 7.0: 'Hospital_4', 8.0: 'Hospital_3', 9.0: 'Hospital_2', 10.0: 'Hospital_1'}, 'Doctor_2': {1.0: 'Hospital_3', 2.0: 'Hospital_2', 3.0: 'Hospital_4', 4.0: 'Hospital_1', 5.0: 'Hospital_5', 6.0: 'Hospital_6', 7.0: 'Hospital_7', 8.0: 'Hospital_8', 9.0: 'Hospital_9', 10.0: 'Hospital_10'}}
```

Hospitals to doctors:

```
{'Hospital_2': {1.0: 'Doctor_1', 2.0: 'Doctor_2', 3.0: 'Doctor_3', 4.0: 'Doctor_4', 5.0: 'Doctor_5', 6.0: 'Doctor_6', 7.0: 'Doctor_7', 8.0: 'Doctor_8', 9.0: 'Doctor_9', 10.0: 'Doctor_10'}, 'Hospital_1': {1.0: 'Doctor_1', 2.0: 'Doctor_2', 3.0: 'Doctor_3', 4.0: 'Doctor_4', 5.0: 'Doctor_5', 6.0: 'Doctor_6', 7.0: 'Doctor_7', 8.0: 'Doctor_8', 9.0: 'Doctor_9', 10.0: 'Doctor_10'}, 'Hospital_8': {1.0: 'Doctor_8', 2.0: 'Doctor_9', 3.0: 'Doctor_7', 4.0: 'Doctor_6', 5.0: 'Doctor_10', 6.0: 'Doctor_4', 7.0: 'Doctor_3', 8.0: 'Doctor_2', 9.0: 'Doctor_1'}, 'Hospital_7': {1.0: 'Doctor_5', 2.0: 'Doctor_6', 3.0: 'Doctor_7', 4.0: 'Doctor_8', 5.0: 'Doctor_3', 6.0: 'Doctor_2', 7.0: 'Doctor_9', 8.0: 'Doctor_1', 9.0: 'Doctor_10'}, 'Hospital_10': {1.0: 'Doctor_10', 2.0: 'Doctor_9', 3.0: 'Doctor_8', 4.0: 'Doctor_7', 5.0: 'Doctor_6', 6.0: 'Doctor_5', 7.0: 'Doctor_4', 8.0: 'Doctor_3', 9.0: 'Doctor_2', 10.0: 'Doctor_1'}, 'Hospital_3': {1.0: 'Doctor_1', 2.0: 'Doctor_2', 3.0: 'Doctor_3', 4.0: 'Doctor_4', 5.0: 'Doctor_5', 6.0: 'Doctor_6', 7.0: 'Doctor_7', 8.0: 'Doctor_8', 9.0: 'Doctor_9', 10.0: 'Doctor_10'}, 'Hospital_9': {1.0: 'Doctor_9', 2.0: 'Doctor_10', 3.0: 'Doctor_8', 4.0: 'Doctor_7', 5.0: 'Doctor_6', 6.0: 'Doctor_5', 7.0: 'Doctor_4', 8.0: 'Doctor_3', 9.0: 'Doctor_2', 10.0: 'Doctor_1'}, 'Hospital_5': {1.0: 'Doctor_4', 2.0: 'Doctor_3', 3.0: 'Doctor_2', 4.0: 'Doctor_1', 5.0: 'Doctor_5', 6.0: 'Doctor_6', 7.0: 'Doctor_7', 8.0: 'Doctor_8', 9.0: 'Doctor_9', 10.0: 'Doctor_10'}, 'Hospital_4': {1.0: 'Doctor_3', 2.0: 'Doctor_2', 3.0: 'Doctor_4', 4.0: 'Doctor_1', 5.0: 'Doctor_5', 6.0: 'Doctor_6', 7.0: 'Doctor_7', 8.0: 'Doctor_8', 9.0: 'Doctor_9', 10.0: 'Doctor_10'}, 'Hospital_6': {1.0: 'Doctor_4', 2.0: 'Doctor_5', 3.0: 'Doctor_6', 4.0: 'Doctor_3', 5.0: 'Doctor_2', 6.0: 'Doctor_1', 7.0: 'Doctor_8', 8.0: 'Doctor_9', 9.0: 'Doctor_10'}}
```

I also created a list of doctors as this is used to create the index of my DataFrame resulting from the algorithm:

```
['Doctor_5', 'Doctor_9', 'Doctor_8', 'Doctor_1', 'Doctor_4', 'Doctor_3', 'Doctor_6', 'Doctor_7', 'Doctor_10', 'Doctor_2']
```

Now I am trying to create an algorithm that assigns doctors to hospitals based on the Gale-Shapley algorithm (knowing specifics is not necessary).

This is what I have come up with so far, I am presenting it in a DataFrame in the end because I find this more clear to interpret:

```
Matches = {}
Matches['Doctors'] = (doctors)
First_round = []
for Doctor_ in ranking_by_doctors:
    First_round.append(ranking_by_doctors[Doctor_].get(1.0))
Matches['First round'] = (First_round)
Matches
Matches_round_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Matches)
Matches_round_1.set_index('Doctors', inplace=True)
Matches_round_1
```

This is my result:[image]

As you can see I am assigning the most preferred hospital of every doctor to that doctor. But I need help with the conditions of my function. As of right now there exist duplicates in my result: both doctor_7 and doctor_8 are matched to hospital_8, similarily hospital_7 is matched to two different doctors. However, I want to add a condition to my function that checks, in cases like these, which doctor the hospital prefers most, matching that doctor and leaving the other doctor unmatched. Afterwards I want to start the whole process again for the unmatched doctors, leading to new results in round 2. For this second round it should be possible that already matched hospitals break their match because a doctor approaches them that they prefer over their first match.

However, after looking at adjusting my function for some hours and exploring google and list comprehension guides for help, I have still not managed to find a solution. That is why I am turning to stackoverflow for help, maybe one of you has seen this problem before and can help me solve it. If you need anymore information than provided above, let me know!

Thank you very much in advance,

Comment: Could you provide your implementation of the Gale-Shapley algorithm? I am asking because, if you have a equal number of proposors and acceptors, doctors and hospitals in your scenario, the output should't contains duplicates. Also, are you sure this is a SMP? Maybe it is a assignment problem and the Hungarian algorithm will suit you better.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Pedro. This is my implementation so far, I am trying to reconstruct the algorithm. Also, I do have a equal number of doctors and hospitals.

Comment: Saying "(knowing specifics is not necessary)" while you are asking for help about the actual algorithm implementation is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the First_round to a dictionary to make it a bit more straight forward. I would also suggest some other structure changes, but more on that afterwards. A solution is to simply pu in an if check to see if the specific hospital has been assigned and then exchange the doctor if he has a better score:

```
def hospital_ranking_of_doctor(hospital, doctor):
    return next(v for k, v in ranking_by_hospital[hospital].items() if v == doctor)

Matches = {}
Matches['Doctors'] = (doctors)
First_round = {}

# We loop through all the doctors one by one
for Doctor_ in ranking_by_doctors:

    # Then we find which hospital the doctor prefers
    favored_hospital = ranking_by_doctors[Doctor_].get(1.0)

    # We test if that hospital has already had a doctor assigned
    if favored_hospital not in First_round:
        # If it has not, then we just assign the current doctor
        First_round[favored_hospital] = Doctor_
    else:
        # If the hosptial was already assigned a doctor we compare 
        # that doctor with the new one and set the new one only if 
        # the hospital prefers him.
        previously_assigned_doctor = First_round[favored_hospital]
        if hospital_ranking_of_doctor(favored_hospital, previously_assigned_doctor) > hospital_ranking_of_doctor(favored_hospital, Doctor_):
            First_round[favored_hospital] = Doctor_

print(First_round)
```

Now for the structure changes, I think you should also either change the ranking structures from being a dictionary ranging numbers to hospitals/doctors, to either just being an ordered list of preferences or flipping it so the key is the hospital/doctor and the priority/score being the value. This would make checking the score of a doctor more natural like:

```
ranking_by_hospital['Hospital_2']['Doctor_2'] > ranking_by_hospital['Hospital_2']['Doctor_3']
```

So you could update the ranking function to be:

```
def hospital_ranking_of_doctor(hospital, doctor):
    return ranking_by_hospital[hospital][doctor]
```

Or simply inline those code bits.

Comment: Hey Vincent, thank you for your answer! I flipped the key and ranking, is this what you mean?
     'Doctor_5': {'Hospital_2': 9.0, 'Hospital_1': 10.0, 'Hospital_3': 8.0, 'Hospital_10': 7.0, 'Hospital_4': 6.0, 'Hospital_7': 1.0, 'Hospital_9': 5.0, 'Hospital_5': 4.0, 'Hospital_8': 3.0, 'Hospital_6': 2.0}

Sorry I don't know how to put this in code format.

This would however stop the .get function from working properly.

Comment: @Jeff, I added an updated ranking function showing what I mean, though it becomes quite short, so you might consider simply inlining that bit. To get code formated in your comments use the single backticks ` around the piece of code. You can click on "help" to the right of the comment field and click on "learn more about formatting" and you also get a reference on all the other supported types of formating.

Comment: Thank you so much! A few more questions if you have the time. What does 'inlining' mean? Moreover, (again only if you have time) could you maybe add some comments to your code to explain what your code is exactly doing in that step. If I copy this it works, which is great! But I would really like to understand it aswell.

Comment: By inlining I mean to take the body of the function and just insert it where you would otherwise call the function so for instance instead of having `def comp(a,b): return a>b` and then somewhere calling `if comp(k,b) and comp(k, x):` you would just call `if k>b and k>x:` This is often done if you have a very short function that isn't used that many places. I've added some comments to the code, hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, it is clear now! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Hello Vincent,
Sorry, but I am stuck again... For the second round I want to add to `if favored_hospital not in First_round:` an and statement defining that the key over which the loop iterates should also not have been previously used. In simpler terms, in the second round a hospital that did not have a doctor assigned in round 1 should not be assigned a doctor already assigned to another hospital in round 1 (the doctor would never go to this hospital, as the one she got in round 1 is her most preferred hospital.) This is how I tried to solve it:

Comment: `Second_round = First_round
for Doctor_ in ranking_by_doctors:
    favored_hospital = ranking_by_doctors[Doctor_].get(2.0)
    if favored_hospital not in Second_round and 'value' not in First_round:
        Second_round[favored_hospital] = Doctor_
    else:
        previously_assigned_doctor = First_round[favored_hospital]
        if hospital_ranking_of_doctor(favored_hospital, previously_assigned_doctor) > hospital_ranking_of_doctor(favored_hospital, Doctor_):
            Second_round[favored_hospital] = Doctor_
Second_round`
But that obviously does not work as:

Comment: `{'Hospital_1': 'Doctor_1',
 'Hospital_10': 'Doctor_10',
 'Hospital_2': 'Doctor_1',
 'Hospital_3': 'Doctor_2',
 'Hospital_4': 'Doctor_3',
 'Hospital_5': 'Doctor_4',
 'Hospital_6': 'Doctor_4',
 'Hospital_7': 'Doctor_5',
 'Hospital_8': 'Doctor_8',
 'Hospital_9': 'Doctor_9'}`

This becomes the new result, Doctor_4 and Doctor_1 are assigned to multiple hospitals.